# Traceability of changes by users in deployment server of web forms published code

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, webforms, traceability

We have a deployment server that has 4 users, the credentials of 3 users have been distributed among the 3 deployments responsible while one is general for connectivity through application to the database. Now someone is changing the code to the previous version, which is not traceable. Is there any way to know who is behind those changes even they have used proxy? I want to write a windows service to log the activities and ips of the user logged in without their knowledge. How i will record the ips with proxy and every activity that a user will perform

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: Have you asked the people who have been given the credentials if they the ones changing the code? It sounds like you should cycle the credentials and wait til someone complains they lost access.